# password_verfiy() returns false with correct credentials

Tags: php, authentication

So I'm creating a simple login page, I've used this exact code in a different project and it works great, now it doesn't work for some reason. I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious but after 1 hour I can't seem to find it.

PHP version: 7.2.5

The login page:

```
<?php require "../db.php";

$username = $password = "";

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $con,  $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $con,  $_POST['password']);

$hash = $con->query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")->fetch_object()->password;

print_r($password);?><br><?php

$hash2 = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo $hash2;?><br><?php

print_r($hash);?><br><?php



var_dump(password_verify($password, $hash));

// if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
//   session_start();
//   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
//   header("Location: ../seldep.php");
//   die();
// }
// else {
//   header("Location: ../index.php?1");
//   die();
// }
}
?>
```

Right now there is a lot of test code there to test it.

If I create a brand new account and try logging in, it returns false, but I change it so it takes the password the user inputs on login and hash that in the same file and put it through password_verify it returns true. It should be the exact same but It doesn't work. Any obvious issues here?

Edit:
Here is the output when trying to login with the username: 5 and password: 5 (This is in the database and was JUST registered.)

```
$2y$10$wjvfZh5EQPoXDGt89JfyXOA2TMq4MfvAQHNPXte939BcH.9y.3Ecm
 $2y$10$L2horMNAcXETSvOPQDCaMOoXtie3VQ4rRWhLhj5OK5.2sqHCnzRWK
  $2y$10$uuQshjMaeepm6aY8.4lBne88tFo5oKem54wztm.dLXT
   bool(false)
    5
```

Update with the form:

```
<form action="accounts/login.php" method="post">
    <div  class="z-depth-3 y-depth-3 x-depth-3 grey green-text lighten-4 
         row" style="display: inline-block; padding: 32px 48px 0px 48px; 
     border: 1px; 
      margin-top: 100px; solid #EEE;">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>

          <h1 class="grey-text" style="font-size: 20px;"> <?php echo 
           CLAN_NAME; ?> </h1>

        <div class='row'>
        <h1 class="grey-text" style="font-size: 20px;"> LOGIN </h1>
          <div class='input-field col s12'>
            <input class='validate' type="text" name='username' required />
            <label for='email'>Username</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='input-field col m12'>
            <input class='validate' type='password' name='password' required 
              />
            <label for='password'>Password</label>
          </div>
          <label style='float: right;'>
          <b style="color: #F5F5F5;">Forgot Password?</b>
          </label>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <center>
          <div class='row'>
            <button style="margin-left:75px;"  type='submit'                 
            name='btn_login' class='col  s6 btn btn-small white black-text  
            waves-effect z-depth-1 y-depth-1'>Login</button>
          </div>
          <div class='row'>
            <a href="accounts/register.php" style="margin-left:75px;" 
            class='col  s6 btn btn-small white black-text  waves-effect z- 
            depth-1 y-depth-1'>Request access</a>
          </div>
        </center>

    </div>
  </form>
```

My bad, here you go: (UPDATE/EDIT)

```
<?php require "../db.php" ?>
 <?php session_start(); ?>

 <?php

 $username = $email = $password = $password2 = "";

 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $con,  $_POST['username']);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $con,  $_POST['email']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $con,  $_POST['password']);
 $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $con,  $_POST['password2']);

if ($password == $password2) {
$hash = password_hash($password2, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$hash')";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  header("Location: register.php?rg");
  die();
  } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
  }
  } else {
  header("Location: register.php?passwordDontMatch");
   }
 }

 ?>
```

Updated with register form:

```
<form action="registerdone.php" method="post">
   <div class="z-depth-3 y-depth-3 x-depth-3 grey green-text lighten-4 row" style="display: inline-block; padding: 32px 48px 0px 48px; border: 1px; margin-top: 100px; solid #EEE;">
   <div class="section"></div>
   <div class="section"></div>
       <div class='row'>
       <h1 class="grey-text" style="font-size: 20px;"> REQUEST ACCESS </h1>
       <!-- Defining the username -->
         <div class='input-field col s12'>
           <input class='validate' type="text" name='username' id='email' required />
           <label for='email'>Username</label>
         </div>
         <!-- Defining the email -->
         <div class='input-field col s12'>
           <input class='validate' type="text" name='email' id='email' required />
           <label for='email'>Email</label>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class='row'>
         <!-- Defining the password -->
         <div class='input-field col m12'>
           <input class='validate' type='password' name='password' id='password' required />
           <label for='password'>Password</label>
         </div>
         <!-- Confirming the passwords matching -->
         <div class='input-field col m12'>
           <input class='validate' type='password' name='password2' id='password' required />
           <label for='password'>Confirm password</label>
         </div>
       </div>
       <br/>
       <center>
         <div class='row'>
           <button style="margin-left:75px;"  type='submit' name='btn_login' class='col  s6 btn btn-small white black-text  waves-effect z-depth-1 y-depth-1'>Request access</button>
         </div>
         <div class='row'>
           <a href="../index.php" style="margin-left:75px;" class='col  s6 btn btn-small white black-text  waves-effect z-depth-1 y-depth-1'>Login page</a>
         </div>
       </center>

   </div>
 </form>
```

Update with the output from this:

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
print_r($hash);?><br><?php
var_dump($hash);?><br><?php
$hash2 = password_hash($password2, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
print_r($hash2);?><br><?php
var_dump($hash2);?><br><?php
die();
```

output is as follows:

```
string(60) "$2y$10$VECqLlJwpndtDSv3r/U4z.4JsIZjXoFUuj7ALkzlFQuTeUKVcK/ze" 
$2y$10$x8MLKNwcvbhY7AoYxPiFyOaEazE2rfS2nbqVetATATuH1QpnwLa96
string(60) "$2y$10$x8MLKNwcvbhY7AoYxPiFyOaEazE2rfS2nbqVetATATuH1QpnwLa96" 
$2y$10$VECqLlJwpndtDSv3r/U4z.4JsIZjXoFUuj7ALkzlFQuTeUKVcK/ze
```

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string ( $con,  $_POST['password']);` you could be braking the password here. no point when your not putting that value in the db.

Comment: Could I? Could you explain more about that do you think, I'm not 100% sure what you mean.

Comment: a. your not putting the string `$_POST['password']`  in to a db, so why would you run `mysqli_real_escape_string` on it. B. if the password contains any character that `mysqli_real_escape_string` escapes you have basically just changed the password, so it would never match. ie my password was `fdrtgvrmjitb'ru` you convert it to `fdrtgvrmjitb\'ru`  but `fdrtgvrmjitb'ru` != `fdrtgvrmjitb\'ru`

Comment: good catch @smith, but if the password is 5, there has to be another issue too, no?

Comment: could be the insert then. post that code

Comment: I see what you mena, and i just tried it, did not solve my issue :( Unfortunatley. Any other thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Updated with the input form

Comment: i meant the code that puts the password in to the db in the first place.

Comment: My bad, updated.

Comment: try and increase your column length to 255 for the password. Possible problem is that the value was cut when it was saved in the database.

Comment: `For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).`

Comment: It is already set to 255 chars so that shouldn't be the problem :( @hungrykoala

Comment: Try inserting and fetching the data without `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: I JUST tried that actually, didn't work that either :(

Comment: Can we see your registration form?

Comment: @SamEzedi yes ofrouce, i've updated it.

Comment: do a die on password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); and a on password_hash($password2, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); check the values it returns

Comment: @SamEzedi i think i updated it with what you wanted.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: nope same problem. @SamEzedi It returns false when the password is correct.

Comment: your values are not same, check both values carefully before inserting into the database, echo them out to know if they are same, the problem is most likely to be from your inputs